Improve Angular performance with 80,000+ DOM elements on screen
I am working with Angular 14. I display a huge amount of data (large DOM sizes) in my page (width: 2208 by height: 3140).
I need to display all this data at one time in an ag grid table. My issue is that the data is so big, and should not use virtual scrollling or pagination, yet I need to display all data on a large screen.
I do not have CSS code or complex JS code. What I did is to add Server Side Rendering, but I have the same problem. My page takes 15 seconds to display data.
With my large screen and displayed data I used this in the console:
 document.querySelectorAll('*').length; 

This shows me 83326.
I am searching if there are any ways to increase the DOM to accept large data and display data on a large screen in 3 or 4 seconds. The data is around 50000 objects.
Is there a package or something that can help me without pagination, virtual scrolling or infinite scrolling, to display data in one shot? enter image description here

The DOM is very slow (comparatively) and dumping 80,000+ elements in to it is never going to be performant, no matter how you create them. The trick is to lighten that weight by only loading those which will be visible. You've already discounted the ways to do that (infinite scrolling/pagination) so there's not really anything else you can do.

Also note that this performance has nothing to do with Angular, and everything to do with how quickly browsers can render the DOM

One solution I can think of is to stream the data to the browser, updating the interface as data comes in.

"Is there a package or something that can help" - Requesting recommendations for off-site resources is explicitly off-topic for [so]

seems like a browser is the wrong tool for the job here.   What's the use-case?  (Who/What is looking at this and for what reason?  What, if any, UI controls are needed?)

@RoryMcCrossan thank you for your response, is the SSR (server side panel) can increase the Dom ?

Potentially, but it's still going to be slow for the amount of elements you're trying to create. There is no avoiding weight of data in your case.
